# makeStyles: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Looking the docs (https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/), this should be possible:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    h2: {
        font-family: '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
    }
});
```

However on attemting to run, I get :

```
  Line 119:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  117 | const useStyles = makeStyles({
  118 |     h2: {
> 119 |         font-family: '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'                                                                     
      |             ^
  120 |     }
  121 | });
  122 |
```

I'm not entirely sure where I've gone wrong ?

Comment: replace font-family with fontFamily if that doesn't work use textStyle attribute

Comment: @nishant yes indeed, I just discovered that: https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#typography

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key with dashes has to be quoted. Try this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    h2: {
        'font-family': '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'                                                                     
    }
});
```

Comment: isn't it also possible to use camel case such as `fontFamily` and it will smartly convert it?

Comment: not familiar with Material-UI, but judging from the docs that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

`font-family` is not a valid identifier, you have to wrap it into quotes:

```
'font-family': ...
```